# Crystal report group/record selection issues

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Ok I'm making my first report from scratch so I'm fairly new to this. I have a report with a subreport I'm working in. This subreport only uses data from one table. Right now I have a group header/details/group footer where it drops in each row from the table on a separate row...I have it set up with a box around the different header/details sections so it forms a grid with a line in between each record.

I need to set up another details section where it splits up the records based on a criteria I choose. Say there is a database field called order and it is from 1-7. How would I go about making sure the records that are only in between say 1-4 are in this first group where it is currently dropping all the records, and then put the rest 5-7 in another identical details section? Would I use a group selection formula in the group selection and if so how would I define it and the two different sections so each one knows which records to use from that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a supression formula, with two identical group sections. On the first one, the supression formula would kick in for `order >= 5`, so the 5,6,7 rows are hidden. In the other, you'd use `order < 5` so this second section is hidden when order is 1,2,3,4.

That duplicates the report logic in the two sections, but does give the effect of splitting up the two sections.

Comment: Ok thanks for the guidance so far and I see what you are saying but I still have a prob when I add a new group though through Insert > Group... It places the new group entirely within the first group and there is no separate details section. How can I get a stand alone header/details/footer for each group 1 and 2 without having them embedded within each other as that looks like it will mess up the formatting of what I want to separate in this "chart". I do not want anything within each section, I want each to be next to and separate of the other.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess you could try writing a grouping function to create a virtual grouping on the 1-4 and 5-6 ranges. Never tried that before (there's some options for it in the group expert section somewhere. the other option is two sub-reports, each doing their own filtering and whatnot. Unfortunately you can't nest subreports in each other (@%@#$@##@$@#$ crystal), so if you're already in a subreport, this won't work.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks so much for your input on this I appreciate it.